# how to place a cliackable overlay on top of another activity in android?

Tags: java, android, overlay

i need to place a view on top of another activity which should have clickable buttons etc. the underlying activity itself MUST NOT be stopped/paused or else.

to be more specific: i want to display some kind of a note when i receive a call. this note should be displayed on top of the incoming-call-activity without disrupting the activity itself or hindering the user from interacting with it...

how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could using an AlertDialog help perhaps?

Comment: hmm... i dont know if this is possible, but i will try.

Comment: if you want to just notify the incoming call means you can use Toast message to notify user..But it will disappear in 2 or 3 seconds..   Toast.makeText(ACTIVITYNAME.this,"Incoming Call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: are you saying that you couldnt get it to work? or that it's not doing what you want it to?

Comment: i couldnt get it to work as an AlertDialog seems to require an Activity-reference to get working...

Comment: Paste some code, and I can help you out with it.... AlertDialogs do need an activity reference, but it is not very hard.